# Segmentation fault raised from stl_list.h : 731

Tags: c++, opengl

I've got a very weird segmentation fault with my code. Actually, when I run my executable, it aborts. When I run it with gdb, it also aborts. But when I run it with valgrind, it terminates successfully and gives me the correct result.

That's for the introduction. Now here's a description of my algorithm. What I want to do is extracting the subsurface of a mesh that looks similar to another one, given a certain threshold, *r*. The key idea of my algorithm is looping on each point of the mesh (let's say, *p*). If I find a point of the reference mesh included in the sphere of center *p* and radius *r*, I don't do anything and I go to the next point. Otherwise, I delete the point and every element of the mesh including it (which means, edges, and triangles of the mesh to which the point belongs).

Now I jump to a short description of my classes. I have four classes to represent elements of the mesh :

- Vertex. This class includes two attributes (I don't mention the getters and setters) : a position and a list, belongsTo, which contains pointers to all of the edges to which the vertex belongs.
- Edge. This class includes three attributes : the two vertices delimiting the edge, and a list, also called belongsTo, wichi contains pointers to all of the triangles to which an edge belongs.
- Triangle. This class includes three attributes : the three edges delimiting the triangle, and a normal vector (I mentioned it, but it doesn't really matter here : I only use it to render the triangle using OpenGL).

And, finally :

- Mesh. This class includes a vector v of Vertex objets, a vector e of Edge objects and finally a vector t of Triangles.

Now here is the prototype of my function :

```
class Mesh {

    ...

    void extractIdenticalSubsurfaces(Mesh *a, double threshold);

}
```

As you may have already guessed, this function takes two parameters into account : the reference mesh and a threshold (actually the radius of the sphere I build to determine if I have to delete the point from the mesh). Is everything clear ?

Description of my algorithm : I loop on each point of the mesh (on each point of v, actually). For each point, I build a sphere of radius 'threshold' centered in this point and I verify it there is a point of a in this sphere. If I find a point, I don't do anything. Otherwise, I delete it from v.

But before doing that, I have some operations to do.

Indeed, I have to loop on each edge to which the point belongs (using the list 'belongsTo') and then on each triangle to which the point belongs (once again using the list 'belongsTo').

For each of these triangles, I loop on the three edges delimiting it and I delete the address of the triangle from the list of edges to which this triangle belongs (because I want to delete this triangle, so I have to anticipate).

Once it's done, I do the same with the current edge of the loop : I delete the adress of the edge from the 'belongsTo' list associated to the two vertices of the edge.

But I also have to delete both suppressed edges and triangles from the vectors e and t !

It may seem not so easy to understand (I think it's better if you have a sheet of paper just in front of you and if you draw a mesh and consider a point that you want to suppress) but I am quite sure of the exactitude of this algorithm : actually, when I run my program with valgrind, it displays the good sub-mesh on my screen.

But the problem is that if I don't use valgrind, it fails.

Here's the error message displayed by gdb :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000406f3a in std::list<Triangle*, std::allocator<Triangle*> >::begin (this=0x39) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_list.h:731
731       { return iterator(this->_M_impl._M_node._M_next); }
```

The backtrace :

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000406f3a in std::list<Triangle*, std::allocator<Triangle*> >::begin (this=0x39) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_list.h:731
#1  0x0000000000406e37 in std::list<Triangle*, std::allocator<Triangle*> >::remove (this=0x39, __value=@0x7fffffffc860) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/list.tcc:242
#2  0x00000000004062a1 in Edge::deleteTriangle (this=0x21, t=0xcf4ed0) at elements.cpp:109
#3  0x0000000000408aa4 in Mesh::extractIdenticalSubsurfaces (this=0xc14b10, a=0xc0f900, threshold=0) at mesh.cpp:174
#4  0x0000000000404687 in Scene::extractIdenticalSurfaces (this=0xbad8c0, threshold=0) at scene.cpp:36
#5  0x00000000004051c6 in Viewer::keyPressEvent (this=0x7fffffffde80, e=0x7fffffffd020) at viewer.cpp:104
...
```

As you can see, getting an error is logical here, because the system seems to try to apply the 'deleteTriangle' method on an object whose 'this' address is 0x21. But what I am wondering is, how on earth can it be 0x21. I tried to dislay the adresses of the pointers to edges and vertices included in all of the Triangles and Edges objects, and they seems to be correct (after all I can display all of the elements of my mesh using OpenGL, so...). But at a moment this 0x21 comes in and I definitely don't know why.

This is my code :

```
void Mesh::extractIdenticalSubsurfaces (Mesh *a, double threshold) {
  vector<Vertex *>::iterator it1 = v.begin() ;
  while (it1 != v.end()) {
    if (a->emptySphere((*it1), threshold)) {
      list<Edge *> edgesToDelete = list<Edge *>();
      list<Triangle *> trianglesToDelete = list<Triangle *>();
      for (list<Edge *>::iterator it2 = (*it1)->getIteratorBegin() ; it2 != (*it1)->getIteratorEnd() ; it2++) {
        for (list<Triangle *>::iterator it3 = (*it2)->getIteratorBegin() ; it3 != (*it2)->getIteratorEnd() ; it3++) {
          Triangle *argT = (*it3);
          (*it3)->getFirstEdge()->deleteTriangle(argT);
          (*it3)->getSecondEdge()->deleteTriangle(argT);
          (*it3)->getThirdEdge()->deleteTriangle(argT);
          trianglesToDelete.push_back(argT);
        }
        Edge *argE = (*it2);
        (*it2)->getFirstVertex()->deleteEdge(argE);
        (*it2)->getSecondVertex()->deleteEdge(argE);
        edgesToDelete.push_back(argE);
      }
      edgesToDelete.unique();
      trianglesToDelete.unique();
      vector<Edge *>::iterator it4 = e.begin();
      while (it4 != e.end()) {
        bool isEqual = false;
        for (list<Edge *>::iterator it5 = edgesToDelete.begin() ; it5 != edgesToDelete.end() ; it5++) {
          if ((*it4) == (*it5)) {
            isEqual = true;
            edgesToDelete.erase(it5);
            break;
          }
        }
        if (isEqual) {
          e.erase(it4);
        } else {
          it4++;
        }
      }
      vector<Triangle *>::iterator it6 = t.begin();
      while (it6 != t.end()) {
        bool isEqual = false;
        for (list<Triangle *>::iterator it7 = trianglesToDelete.begin() ; it7 != trianglesToDelete.end() ; it7++) {
          if ((*it6) == (*it7)) {
            isEqual = true;
            trianglesToDelete.erase(it7);
            break;
          }
        }
        if (isEqual) {
          t.erase(it6);
        } else {
          it6++;
        }   
      }
      v.erase(it1);
    } else {
      it1++;
    }
  }
}
```

(Well, not very pretty sometimes, I agree but this isn't the subject of my question (on first sight))

So, do you have any idea of why I get this error ?

Comment: This code : oh my eyes!

Comment: This is a damn fine second question. Congrats, Mukyu.

Comment: `Ive got a very weird segmentation fault with my code.`  Given the code you posted, you would consider it "weird" if a segmentation fault occurs?  Why don't you use some STL algorithm(s) to do this work much more safely and cleanly?

Comment: You are erasing items from vector: erasing elements in positions other than the vector end causes the container to relocate all the elements.

Comment: @AbhiP - exactly.  Erasing items in a vector while iterating over the vector -- a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @Mukyu - You should rethink your loop. Instead of attempting to erase items in the vector v while you're iterating over it, use an algorithm to place the deleted items at the end of the vector.

Then once the loop is finished, then erase those items. Algorithms such as std::partition and std::remove_if can do this work for you (partition the bad items to the end of the vector, then when work is done, finish up by removing the items).

Comment: Thanks you for all of these comments. You were right, it was a matter of order in the deletions : now that I've rewrote the code taking this aspect into account, it works fine. Thanks you again !